# Since when does 3 / 5 = 0?

Tags: c#, math, ncalc

So I've got a nice convoluted piece of C# code that deals with substitution into mathematical equations. It's working almost perfectly. However, when given the equation `(x - y + 1) / z` and values `x=2` `y=0` `z=5`, it fails miserably and inexplicably.

The problem is not that the values are passed to the function wrong. That's fine. The problem is that no matter what type I use, C# seems to think that 3/5=0.

Here's the piece of code in question:

```
public static void TrapRule(string[] args)
    {
        // ...

        string equation = args[0];
        int ordinates = Convert.ToInt32(args[1]);
        int startX = Convert.ToInt32(args[2]);
        int endX = Convert.ToInt32(args[3]);
        double difference = (endX - startX + 1) / ordinates;

        // ...
    }
```

It gets passed `args` as:

```
args[0] = Pow(6,[x])
args[1] = 5
args[2] = 0
args[3] = 2
```

(Using NCalc, by the way, so the `Pow()` function gets evaluated by that - which works fine.)

The result? `difference = 0`.

The same thing happens when using `float`, and when trying simple math:

```
Console.Write((3 / 5));
```

produces the same result.

What's going on?

Comment: Try use the `float` type: `3f / 5`.

Comment: When you say "no matter what type I use", do you mean you're changing the type of just `difference`? Or of `ordinates`, `startX`, and `endX`?

Comment: 3/5 is not float.  That is integer arithmetic, as are your variables.

Comment: @OldProgrammer In this case yes, but in other cases it can be doubles

Comment: "Since when does 3 / 5 = 0?" Always, you're doing integer division.

Comment: 3/5 = 0 sounds right to me, now 3.0/5.0 that sounds like .60

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ program converts fahrenheit to celsius](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217842/c-program-converts-fahrenheit-to-celsius)

Comment: @tmyklebu ...how? This is C#, that's C++; this has nothing to do with temperature conversion. While they have some similarities, this is a different question.

Comment: @ArtOfCode: They're fundamentally the same.  Those trivial differences do not make your question not-a-duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The / operator looks at its operands and when it discovers that they are two integers it returns an integer. If you want to get back a double value then you need to cast one of the two integers to a double

```
double difference = (endX - startX + 1) / (double)ordinates;
```

You can find a more formal explanation in the [C# reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

They're called integers. Integers don't store any fractional parts of a number. Moreover, when you divide an integer divided by another integer... the result is still an integer.

So when you take 3 / 5 in integer land, you can't store the .6 result. All you have left is 0. The fractional part is always truncated, never rounded. Most programming languages work this way.

For something like this, I'd recommend working in the `decimal` type, instead.