# c++ Fahrenheit or Celsius converter

Tags: c++

Hi Just wondering why this is not working, as of right now it prints out just the Fahrenheit one no matter if i select c or f. plz help

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    char unit;
    float degrees = 0.0;
    float Farenheit, Celsius;

   cout << "Enter the temperature unit you are currently in (f or c): ";
   cin >> unit;
   cout << "Enter the temperature in degrees: ";
   cin >> degrees;

   if ( unit == 'c' || 'C')
   {
      Farenheit = (degrees - 32) / 9 * 5.0;
      cout << "The degrees in Farenheit are: " << Farenheit << endl;
   }

   else if ( unit == 'f' || 'F')
   {
      Celsius = (degrees - 32) * 5.0/9;
      cout << "The degrees in Celsius is: " << Celsius << endl;
   }

   return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Do a minimum of research before posting a new question here please!

Comment: `||` does not work the way you think!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ program converts fahrenheit to celsius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217842/c-program-converts-fahrenheit-to-celsius)

Answer (score 3):

This might work better:

```
if ( unit == 'c' || unit == 'C')
```

Comment: Wouldn't a comment suffice? How does this relate to the question title?

Comment: Thank you my friend

Comment: It spells out that the code posted wasn't doing what the OP thought it was.

Comment: Or `if (toupper(unit) == 'C')`.  Or even `if (strchr("Cc", unit))`.

Comment: Yes any of those would be better.